# I don't know how these files got in my photos

Tags: file-system

I get photos saved in a folder named files, I don't know the people in the pictures . there not photos I took ! How could they have gotten into my phone? and details show /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.littleengine.wordpal/files/ .......plz help.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the Data asociated to an app called World Wars maybe some other (you can google "com.littleengine.wordpal" to know what aplication is, that is the package name), it's possible those photos are there because are saved data from gameplays or other players avatars, in this case there is not too much to worry about, except for the space of course. If you don't trust the source of the application i recommento to uninstall it, but if you installed it from the Play Store there are almost sure not problem at all.
Anyway, if there is not such application like World Wars or any other, find that folder with the pics and delete it, there'll no be problem, if the folder appears again, consider to install an antivirus or something

Comment: Google Play as origin != safe apps.

Comment: It's true, Google Play =! safe apps, but if Google finds out that an app contains malware, bye bye, app!

Comment: If you take a closer look at the application, you can see that these pictures in the particular folder are profile pictures from the app. So the app uses this so-called folder `files` as a temp folder. If you are using this game regularly and you are annoyed by these pictures in your gallery app, you should exclude this folder.